# to_dict() changes dtype from int32 to int64

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unit-testing

I am using

```py
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(expected,actual)
```

for unit testing,

```
expected = pd.Dataframe(actual.to_dict()) .
```

But pandas to_dict() function is implicitly changing the dtype from int32 to int64. How should I avoid it?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_dict` isn't changing the dtype to int64.

`to_dict` returns a dict full of ordinary Python scalars, not NumPy or Pandas objects.  An ordinary Python int *has no dtype*. When you call `pandas.DataFrame` again, pandas infers dtypes for all columns, and the inference has no information about the original dtypes.

You'll have to use something other than `to_dict`, or keep track of the original dtypes separately and fix them after reconstructing the dataframe.